# Hyperledger composer modeling language, how to import concepts into another model file

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

In my project, I have 2 asset namespaces

```
namespace org.example.grid



namespace org.example.workload
```

both of them uses a abstract structure called metrics, I want to create 1 concept in a separate file and have both the assets use this concept.

So I made a file like this:

```
namespace org.example.concepts

concept Metrics {
  o Integer metric1
  o Integer metric2
  o Integer metric3
}
```

Then I try to include the Metric concept to asset like so:

namespace org.example.grid
import org.example.concepts.Metrics

```
asset Grid identified by gridId {
    o String gridId
    o Metrics capacity
}
```

However, when trying to create a new grid asset, I get this error:

> Error: transaction returned with failure: TypeNotFoundException: Type Metrics is not defined in namespace org.example.grid

Are concept imports not supported? Or is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, I run your code. It successfully gives me an OutPut.

1) 1st model file **org.example.cocepts**

[image]

2) 2nd Model file **org.example.workload**

[image]

3) 3rd model file **org.example.grid** which contain **Grid** asset and I import **org.example.concepts** file which having **Metrics** **concept**.

[image]

4) Successfully created a **Grid** Asset.

[image]

Hope you will find an error in your structure. :)